# Simulating the back button on the UINavigationController on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I currently have a TableView inside a NavigationController where when a item is selected the following code is ran:

```
DetailViewController *DetailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:DetailViewController animated:YES];
[DetailViewController release];
DetailViewController = nil;
```

This loads up my detail view, however my question is this... How can I call the backbutton on the navigation controller without pressing it? Or how can set it back to the table view (which is what the backbutton does)?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can call the popViewController method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: spank yew, just what I was after :)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```